# Java 8 Lambda to convert Number[][] to double[][]

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, 2d, java-8

```
Number[][] intArray = new Integer[][]{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
double[][] doubleArray = Arrays.stream(intArray)
                            .forEach(pArray -> Arrays.stream(pArray)
                                                .mapToDouble(d ->d.doubleValue())
                                                .toArray())
                            .toArray();
```

I want to convert a Number[][] to double[][]. The above lambda does not work, the outer toArray does not compile.

Arrays.stream(intArray) : Returns a stream of Integer[]

forEach : For every Integer[], creating a stream of Integers, converting each Integer into double and returning a double[]. 

The for each creates the double[] and I thought the outer toArray would return an array of this double[] 

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how you could do it:

```
double[][] doubleArray = Arrays.stream(intArray)
                               .map(arr -> Stream.of(arr).mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).toArray())
                               .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

This can be decomposed as follows:

First you use `Arrays.stream` to create a `Stream<Number[]>`. Then for each `Number[]`, you create a `Stream<Number>`, and use `mapToDouble` to get `DoubleStream` and then `toArray()` to get the `double[]` array.

The final `toArray` call transforms this `Stream<double[]>` into a `double[][]` array.

Answer (score 3):

First of all `forEach` is terminal operator with return type of `void` so you can't use

```
stream().forEach(...).toArray();
//                   ^void returned here, and void doesn't have `toArray` method
```

You need to `map` your data into `double[]` rows, and then collect them into `double[][]`, which brings us to your second problem since `toArray()` (from stream of objects) returns `Object[]` array which can't be stored in `double[][]` reference. You need to use

```
A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)
```

which will return correct type of data, so you can use

```
toArray(size -> new double[size][])
```

or its shorter version

```
toArray(double[][]::new)
```

Here is how your code can look like:

```
double[][] doubleArray = Arrays.stream(intArray)
        .map(
                pArray -> Arrays
                .stream(pArray)
                .mapToDouble(d -> d.doubleValue())
                .toArray()
        ).toArray(double[][]::new);
        //which is equivalent of
//      ).toArray(size -> new double[size][]);

//---[Test]---
for (double[] row : doubleArray){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```